# When does an input field value equals '', null or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

In which cases do an input field value equals `''`, `null` or `undefined`.

I'm trying to check empty fields

```
if($('#cur').val() == 'undefined' || $('#cur').val() == '' || $('#cur').val() == 'null'){
    alert('Blank');
}
```

Comment: To check for undefined or null, you don't use quotes around them.

Comment: Just to mention, `$('#cur').val() == 'undefined'` will return true if the user entered the word `undefined`. The same applies to 'null'. If you want to check for `null` or `undefined` do the following `a === null`, `b === undefined`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value of an `input` element will always be a string. You can safely just compare to the empty string:

```
if($("#cur").val() === "") {
    alert("Blank");
}
```

You are currently checking for the string literals "undefined" and "null". That would only be the case if the value of the `input` was actually the string "undefined" or "null". For example:

```
<!--This would be blank according to your original test-->
<input type="text" value="undefined">
```

It may be worth noting that if the `input` contains blank spaces but nothing else, and you want to count that as empty, the above will not suffice. You can use the jQuery `trim` function to remove leading/trailing white space from a string:

```
if($.trim($("#cur").val()) === "") {
    alert("Blank");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want get `null`, you can set input property to `disabled`:

```
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="value" disabled />
```

Only in this way you can get `null`.